# 行こう with a reading of ゆこう

Tags: readings

In one of the opening songs for the TV show ちびまる子かちゃん the singer says

> 友達 探しに 行こうよ

https://i.gyazo.com/a349820aaf28ca1f13c1c772d889ac2e.png

but 行こう is pronounced ゆこう instead of いこう

Why is 行こう being pronounced this way?